# Irregularities in korban specifications

Tags: korban, pinchas

When listing korbanot, Torah specifies "unblemished" immediately for all days except for Shavuot, where this requirement seems to be added later as an afterthought:

[Bamidbar 28:3, tamid](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.3?lang=bi):

> כְּבָשִׂ֨ים בְּנֵֽי־שָׁנָ֧ה **תְמִימִ֛ם** שְׁנַ֥יִם לַיּ֖וֹם עֹלָ֥ה תָמִֽיד

[28:9, shabat](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.9?lang=bi):

> שְׁנֵֽי־כְבָשִׂ֥ים בְּנֵֽי־שָׁנָ֖ה **תְּמִימִ֑ם**

[28:11, rosh chodesh](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.11?lang=bi):

> כְּבָשִׂ֧ים בְּנֵי־שָׁנָ֛ה שִׁבְעָ֖ה **תְּמִימִֽם**

[28:19, pesach](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.19?lang=bi):

> וְשִׁבְעָ֤ה כְבָשִׂים֙ בְּנֵ֣י שָׁנָ֔ה **תְּמִימִ֖ם** יִהְי֥וּ לָכֶֽם

[28:27, shavuot](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.27?lang=bi) - "unblemished" is omitted:

> שִׁבְעָ֥ה כְבָשִׂ֖ים בְּנֵ֥י שָׁנָֽה

[28:31, afterthought](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.31?lang=bi):

> **תְּמִימִ֥ם** יִהְיוּ־לָכֶ֖ם

[29:2, rosh hashana](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.2?lang=bi):

> כְּבָשִׂ֧ים בְּנֵי־שָׁנָ֛ה שִׁבְעָ֖ה **תְּמִימִֽם**

[29:8, yom kippur](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.8?lang=bi):

> כְּבָשִׂ֤ים בְּנֵֽי־שָׁנָה֙ שִׁבְעָ֔ה **תְּמִימִ֖ם** יִהְי֥וּ לָכֶֽם

[29:13, sukkot 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.13?lang=bi),
[29:17, sukkot 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.17?lang=bi),
[29:20, sukkot 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.20?lang=bi),
[29:23, sukkot 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.23?lang=bi),
[29:26, sukkot 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.26?lang=bi),
[29:29, sukkot 6](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.29?lang=bi),
[29:32, sukkot 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.32?lang=bi):

> כְּבָשִׂ֧ים בְּנֵֽי־שָׁנָ֛ה אַרְבָּעָ֥ה עָשָׂ֖ר **תְּמִימִ֥ם** יִהְיֽוּ

[29:35, shemini atzres](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29.36?lang=bi):

> כְּבָשִׂ֧ים בְּנֵי־שָׁנָ֛ה שִׁבְעָ֖ה **תְּמִימִֽם**

Are there any explanations for these irregularities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't an afterthought; it is a deliberate *semichus* where the Torah places the law of *temimim* next to the *nesachim* to teach that this law applies to the *nesachim* as well as the *Korban* itself.

Gemara (Menachos 87a):

> רבי יוסי בר׳ יהודה אומר שיש בו קמחין פסול שנאמר תמימים
> יהיו לכם ומנחתם תמימים יהיו לכם ונסכיהם.

> Rabbi Yosei, son of Rabbi Yehuda, says: Wine in which there is flour-like white scum is unfit for libations, as it is stated with regard to animal offerings: “Unblemished they shall be for you…and their meal offering shall be fine flour mixed with oil…unblemished they shall be for you, and their libations” (Numbers 28:19–20, 31). This indicates that animal offerings, meal offerings, and libations must all be brought from flawless products. Therefore, the presence of flour-like white scum in wine renders it unfit. (Sefaria translation)

The *Netziv* writes in *Ha'amek Davar* that is isn't accidental that the Torah chose to allude to this law by Shavuos:

> תמימים יהיו לכם ונסכיהם – מכאן למדו במנחות (פז,א) דיין שיש בו קמחין פסול, שנאמר ״תמימים יהיו לכם ונסכיהם״ — הנסכים יהיו גם כן תמימים. ורמזה התורה ביחוד בזה החג, משום שאז שכיח קלקול ביינות, כדתנן בב״ב (צח,א) ׳יין מבושם אני מוכר לך, חייב להעמיד לו עד העצרת׳, ופירש רשב״ם שמכאן ואילך מתקלקל אפילו יין מבושם. כן שמעתי מהרב הגאון מהור״ר אלעזר משה שיחיה האב״ד דק״ק פינסק.

[Summary:] The reason why the Torah chose to teach us this by the festival of Shevuos more than any other festival is because during this season, it is the most likely to occur, as evident from Rashi in Baba Basra (98a).

Comment: Any chance you could add translations? Thank you!